# How to extract character string dynamically from character vector r

Tags: r, regex, extract

Here are three character vectors:

```
[1] "Session_1/Focal_1_P1/240915_P1_S1_F1.csv"
[2] "Session_2/Focal_1_PA10/250915_PA10_S2_F1.csv"
[3] "Session_3/Focal_1_DA100/260915_DA100_S3_F1.csv"
```

I'm trying to extract the strings `P1`, `PA10` and `DA100`, respectively in a standardised manner (as I have several hundred other strings in which I want to extract this.

I know I need to use `regex` but I'm fairly new to it and not exactly sure which one.

I can see that the commonalities are 6 numbers (`\d\d\d\d\d\d`)followed by an `_` and then what I want followed by another `_`.

How do I extract what I want? I believe with `grep` but am not 100% on the regular expression I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub`.  We match zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by a forward slash (`\\/`), followed by one or more numbers and a underscore (`\\d+_`), or (`!`) two instances of an underscore followed by one or more characters that are not an underscore (`(_[^_]+){2}`) and replace it with blank (`""`).

```
gsub(".*\\/\\d+_|(_[^_]+){2}", "", v1)
#[1] "P1"    "PA10"  "DA100"
```

---

Or we extract the `basename` of the vector, match one or more numbers followed by underscore (`\\d+_`) followed by character not an underscore (`([^_]+)`) as a capture group followed by characters until the end of the string and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) for the captured group.

```
sub("\\d+_([^_]+).*", "\\1", basename(v1))
#[1] "P1"    "PA10"  "DA100"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c( "Session_1/Focal_1_P1/240915_P1_S1_F1.csv",
       "Session_2/Focal_1_PA10/250915_PA10_S2_F1.csv",
       "Session_3/Focal_1_DA100/260915_DA100_S3_F1.csv")
```